# Centering table with 4 images in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to center a table containing 4 images and a foot note in beamer (the lines are only for debug). This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % acentos
\usepackage{listings} % incluir código
\usepackage{caption}  % titulos para los listings
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{centering}
        \begin{tabular}{ | r | l | }
            \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Isodata} \\
            \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Huang} &
            \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Default} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}}{\tiny \center Imagen binarizada mediante el algoritmo Isodata (arriba a la derecha), el algoritmo de Huang (abajo a la izquierda) y el algoritmo por defecto (abajo a la derecha)} \\

        \end{tabular}
    \end{centering}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This is however the result I am getting:

[image]

I dont understand why it behaves that way. How can I properly center that table?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Your images seem to be too large, as the caption overlaps the navigation bar!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer all the images are the same size, and they dont have any white margins. What I don't understand is why the table is not horizantaly centered

Comment: `\centering` is a command, not an environment. Remove `\end{centering}` (This does not solve the problem, however)

Comment: Why does the second column behaves like if it had to extend to the full size of the page? (this is what happens with smaller images, btw http://i.imgur.com/0dENSzi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `\multicolumn` command, i.e. the parbox in it -- the OP used basically the whole `\textwidth` for the width of that `\multicolumn`.

Since both images have `0.325\textwidth`, it's basically sufficient to use `0.65\textwidth` for the `\parbox`. (Not taking into account any other `\tabcolsep`)

I added some 'improvements' -- remove `demo` from the options to the beamer class for production run!

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % acentos
\usepackage{calc}%
\usepackage{listings} % incluir código
\usepackage{caption}  % titulos para los listings
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
      \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2} &
      \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Isodata} \tabularnewline
      \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Huang} &
      \includegraphics[width=0.325\textwidth]{img/g2Default} \tabularnewline
      \multicolumn{2}{p{0.65\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}{\tiny \centering Imagen binarizada mediante el algoritmo Isodata (arriba a la derecha), el algoritmo de Huang (abajo a la izquierda) y el algoritmo por defecto (abajo a la derecha)}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]